# SQL - SELECT DISTINCT em apenas um campo

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, postgis

Então, eu estou fazendo uma pesquisa na qual retorna as geometrias que não se repetem (que tem como nome de camada Acesso e Meio):

```
SELECT DISTINCT geo_geometria
FROM geral_elemento_cartografico
WHERE ds_camada LIKE ('%MEIO%') OR ds_camada LIKE ('%ACESSO%')
```

porém, eu gostaria que aparecesse ao lado do retorno, a coluna `ds_camada` também (como a seguinte query), como se distinct agisse somente no geo_geometria, já que o conteúdo das camadas se repetem

```
SELECT DISTINCT geo_geometria, ds_camada
FROM geral_elemento_cartografico
WHERE ds_camada LIKE ('%MEIO%') OR ds_camada LIKE ('%ACESSO%')
```

porém, de 4533 retornos ele pega agora 5602 retornos

alguém sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O PostgreSQL tem a cláusula DISTINCT ON. Para o seu caso ficaria:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(geo_geometria) geo_geometria, ds_camada
FROM geral_elemento_cartografico
WHERE ds_camada LIKE ('%MEIO%') OR ds_camada LIKE ('%ACESSO%')
```